# How create computed alias from Ember.Object to an controller's property?

Tags: ember.js, appkit, ember-app-kit

My global issue is create an ACL object in controller that provide list of all actions, just a part of them available for use. Accessible of actions depends on controllers properties. I like to make an computed property from each of `actions` to controller's property. How to create computed property from controller's nested object's property to controller's property? I did create snippet to illustrate my question.

```js
var App = window.App = Ember.Application.create();

var AccessibleMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
  list: [
    Ember.Object.createWithMixins({
      name: "Permitted to write",
      isAccessible: Ember.computed.alias('isWritable')
    }),
    Ember.Object.createWithMixins({
      name: "Permitted to read",
      isAccessible: Ember.computed.alias('isReadable')
    })
  ]
});


App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(AccessibleMixin, {
  model: {
    isWritable: true,
    isReadable: false
  },
  init: function() {
    var first = this.get('list.firstObject');
    console.log(first);
  },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//wheely.github.io/ember-dialog/css/ember.dialog.min.css">
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="//builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.8.1/ember.prod.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each list}}
    <div>{{name}}: {{#if isAccessible}}YES{{else}}NO{{/if}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your context has switched, the model is no longer in scope when you change the scope to `list`... That's ultimately a large problem here, your list is at a different scope than your model, so it can't alias to anything within the model

Comment: I understand it. Actually I know that is some kind wrong to do so. But would like know is it somehow possible do? An decorator-method `meta` can help?